# NewRelic Ignore cometd LongPolling in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, long-polling, newrelic, cometd

I have a Java Web app running on Jetty which connects to the server using cometD to receive data and returns after 25s if the server has no data and reconnects, i.e., long-polling.

I monitor the performance of the server using NewRelic but those long-polling connections skew the performance diagrams.

Is there a way to tell newrelic to actually ignore the time the server is waiting and only show the actual time that the server has been busy? I understand that it is probably impossible to do this on the newrelic side, but I thought there may be some best practices on how to deal with long-polling connections in newrelic.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to just exclude or ignore the time the server is waiting and only show the actual time that the server has been busy, but what you can do is ignore the transaction completely if you do not need to see those metrics.  https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/java-agent-api This documentation talks about using New Relics API for ignoring transactions.

Answer (score 0):

CometD sends long polls to a URL that is the base CometD Servlet URL with "/connect" appended, see parameter `appendMessageTypeToURL` in the [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/javascript.html#javascript_configure).

For example, if you have mapped the CometD Servlet to `/cometd/*`, then long polls are sent to `/cometd/connect`.

I don't know NewRelic, but perhaps you can filter out the requests that end in `*/connect` and gather your statistics on the other requests, that now won't be skewed by the long poll timeout.